# GEE Logistic Model with Subject Specific Predictions?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-estimating-equations, marginal-model

I have fit a marginal logistic model or GEE Logistic Regression model using SAS' proc genmod to obtain estimated parameters associated with mortality (death).  Using SAS, I am able to obtain subject-level predictions, $\hat{p}$.  However, as I understand it, marginal models are population average models, so does it make sense to obtain these subject-level predictions?  I was thinking about taking these $\hat{p}$'s and making prediction of death based on a cut-point and then performing a cross-validation with the actual known values of death as a means to validate my model. Does it make sense to do this with individual level predictions with GEE?

Answer (score 2):

You will obtain predictions of the same type as you obtain in other standard statistical models, that is, conditional on covariates. Subject-specific predictions you would again if you could also condition on the specific outcome data of a subject, which is not possible for GEEs.

In any case, it makes sense to cross-validate these predictions to see the degree of potential over-fitting in your data.